# Quarkus with JDBI

Tags: java, datasource, quarkus, jdbi3

I'am using [quarkus](https://quarkus.io/) with [JDBI](https://jdbi.org/).
Is there any equivalent to [Spring's](https://spring.io/) class [TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.class](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.html)  which will wrap DataSource forcing [JDBI](https://jdbi.org/) to get an existinga Connection associated with the current transaction, when it requests a new Connection.

Comment: You can try to adapt code like that:
https://github.com/ApolloFoundation/Apollo/tree/master/apl-core/src/main/java/com/apollocurrency/aplwallet/apl/core/db/cdi/transaction/

*JdbiTransactionalInterceptor*

first of all and other related classes

But we use it with Weld now and think about adoption for Quarkus, if that will be possible.